# OpenCV: how to create .vec file to use with opencv_traincascade

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

As I explained in my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086142/opencv-detectmultiscale-gives-too-many-points-out-of-the-object/35091458?noredirect=1#comment57905721_35091458), I am trying to generate some `cascade.xml` files to recognize euro coins to be used in my iOS app. Anyway, I am founding many difficulties in understanding how to generate a .vec file to give as input to `opencv_traincascade`. This because I heard many dissenting views: someone told me that vector file must include only positive images containing only the object to recognize; someone else instead (and also as read in my tutorials) said that vector file must include "samples" images, in other words random backgrounds to which the object to recognize has been added by `opencv_createsamples`. In oter words with:

`opencv_createsamples -img positives/1.png -bg negatives.txt -info 1.txt -num 210 -maxxangle 0.0 -maxyangle 0.0 -maxzangle 0.9 -bgcolor 255 -bgthresh 8 -w 48 -h 48`

which generated 12000 images.
Finally, I have created the .vec file with:

`cat *.txt > positives.txt`

`opencv_createsamples -info positives.txt -bg negatives.txt -vec 2.vec -num 12600 -w 48 -h 48`

So, I would like to ask you which the correct images to be contained in vector files from the following two:

[image]

[image]

Moreover, which is the final command to give to launch the training? This is the ones I have used up to now:

`opencv_traincascade -data final -vec 2.vec -bg negatives.txt -numPos 12000 -numNeg 3000 -numStages 20 -featureType HAAR -precalcValBufSize 2048 -precalcIdxBufSize 2048  -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -w 48 -h 48 -mode ALL`

where the .vec files contains 12000 samples images (background + coin to recognize).
Should the .vec file contain only positive images (only coins), how shall I tell `opencv_traincascade` to train using the samples images?

I really need to know how to do things correctly because I have launched many training which then lead to no correct result and since they take many hours or days to execute, I can't waste time anymore.

Thank to all for your attention.

**UPDATE**
I managed to create a `cascade.xml` file with LBP. See what happens if I give one of the image used as training samples to a simple OpenCV program:

[image]

while with an image like the following:

[image]

it does not work at all. I really don't know where I am making the mistake.

**UPDATE**
Maybe firstly converting positive images to gray scale could help?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've used the `negative samples` database of the INRIA training http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/data/human/

and this input (png with alpha transparency around the coin):

[image]

using this with this command:

`opencv_createsamples -img pos_color.png -num 10 -bg neg.txt -info test.dat -maxxangle 0.6 -maxyangle 0 -maxzangle 0.3 -maxidev 100
 -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0`

produces output like this:

[image]

[image]

so background color obviously didn't work. Converting to grayscale in the beginning however gives me this input:

[image]

and same command produces output like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I know this is no answer to all of your questions, but maybe it still helps.

Comment: Thank you very very much Micka's!! I will try at once to create samples with coins images in grayscale. I'll let you know. Thank you from heart

Comment: Thank you for you answer but it really does not work. First I converted all my images to grayscale with `convert ../0.png -colorspace Gray 0.png` and then I launched the command you posted but the output was the same...nothing to do. Thank you anyway

Comment: is the background black in your grayscale image? It must really be value 0. If you checked that and still doesnt work, please upload such a grayscale input image.

Comment: it's not black. I have tried to convert both by gimp and by `convert` (from image magic) but the background is not black...hod did you do that? You can see ax example in my question I have just updated

Comment: in gimp just delete the background (mark a circle and invert the selection) and color it black (or any other constant color that you set the parameter to)

Comment: Ok, I guess I have made it with this command `convert 0.png -fill black -opaque none 0.jpg`

Comment: there is a thing which is unclear to me...should I want consider all the possible rotations (360°) of the coin around the z-axis (in other words the coin could be more or less "upside down"), which value for `-maxzangle ` shall I set?

Comment: sorry, I have no experience in actual training of haar classifier :-(

Comment: Don't worry. Your help has been very useful and kind. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV cascades (HAAR, LBP) can excellently detect objects which have permanent features.  As example all faces have nose, eyes and mouth at the same places. OpenCV cascades are trained to search common features in required class of object and ignore features which changes from object to object. The problem is conclude that the cascade uses rectangular shape of search window, but a coin has round shape. Therefore an image of the coin always will be have part of background. 
So training images of the coin must includes all possible backgrounds in order to classifiers can ignore them (otherwise it will be detect coin only on the specific background).

So all training samples must have the same image ratio, size and position of the coin (square images with coin in center, diameter of coin = 0.8-0.9 image width), and different background!

Comment: My training samples are all similar to the onw I posted in question. As you can see I have many images like that, with the coin and many possibile backgrounds... Aren't they correct?

Comment: I would add a bit of background on the edges in order to the classifier can use the edge of the coin.

Comment: I know but that's a problem of `opencv_createsamples`. I mean, if I use a 2€ coin downloaded from google images, then those 4 corners are not put in the sample image. If I use a png image created by gimp (with circular crop) and obtained from the frames of a short video, then there are those 4 corners. Do you know how to fix it or where I am making a mistake?

Comment: if you create the images with GIMP you can easily use the alpha channel to remove the corners during insertion of the coin.

Comment: @Micka I use gimp only to crop the photos with the coin. Then the composition with a random background is done by `opencv_createsamples`, not with gimp

Comment: @LoryLory http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html says you can use parameter `-bgcolor <background_color = 0>` to define a background color which is interpreted as being transparent. You might be able to set it to the color of the image border, where the coint isn't 'active'.

Comment: I had read that and I had set bgcolor = 255 or = 0 but this is ignored...there are always those 4 corners

Comment: for me it is working... however i converted my input to grayscale first