# Non-Transformed Object detection with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

What I'm trying to do is to detect 2D objects in an image. The differences between this and typical eyes/faces detection however is that the 2D objects I'm trying to detect are not transformed in any way except *scaled*, *rotated* or *partially blocked* (ex. a certain icon in a computer screenshot.)

I have tried to train a Haar cascade with one positive image (the object) and 600 negative image (randomly selected from a background image), however the result was not satisfactory. In particular, `opencv_createsamples` create weirdly scaled samples (parts are cut off, some are scaled too big). These were the parameters I used:

```bash
# Create samples
opencv_createsamples -img positive_images/icon.png -bg negatives.txt\
  -num 1500 -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 0  -maxyangle 0 -maxzangle 6.28\
  -maxidev 40 -vec pos.vec -maxscale 2 -w 25 -h 25

# Train cascade
opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec pos.vec -bg negatives.txt\
  -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 1000\
  -numNeg 600 -w 25 -h 25 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 4096\
  -precalcIdxBufSize 4096
```

Since the task seems to be simpler than a general object detection task, I'm wondering if there are better ways of doing this. If not, what are some possible ways to get a better result?

---

Edit, here are some sample images that I'm using:

Sample (positive) object:
[image]

Sample backgrounds (2 of 600):
[image] [image]

Some interesting things is that I tried directly using both `opencv_createsamples` (above) and the wrapper provided [here](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) ([direct link](https://github.com/mrnugget/opencv-haar-classifier-training/blob/master/bin/createsamples.pl)). With `opencv_createsamples` the result was not satisfactory. It was not detecting the sample image and classifying other unrelated objects as positive. With the wrapper however the result was a bit better but it only detects the object when there is a white background. I am not sure why using the wrapper would have that effect, but there might be a chance that my parameters, or the way I'm using, was incorrect.

Directory structure:

```
- positive_images/
    - icon.png
- negative_images/
    - 600 images
- classifier/
- positives.txt
- negatives.txt
```

Comment: How about using feature detectors?

Comment: @Zindarod The image might contain multiple objects of the same kind, so I'm not sure if feature detectors would work.

Comment: Please include a few sample images.

Comment: yeah... createsamples doesn't work well if original image (of item) has different width and height (if that's the case). Because when it rotates them it just cuts off the image. But there is a way to prevent it creating too big images. `-maxscale`

Comment: @Zindarod I have added some details and sample images that I am using to train the cascade classifier. Thanks!

Comment: did you control, whether merging the object with the background did work? If there is a mistake, the alpha channel might not be applied correctly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125138/opencv-how-to-create-vec-file-to-use-with-opencv-traincascade/35130506#35130506

Comment: @Micka I actually didn't think of converting the image into grayscale before sending it to `createsamples`. It might fix the white background only problem that I will have to test it out later.

Comment: one additonal comment: just converting to grayscale might not be enough. According to the comments under that answer, you'll have to fill be opaque pixels to black (or the value you want to use as background value)